# bootstrap change navbar .active background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar in which I can't really see the .active color as I am using a 3rd party theme that I really like, but however I have one problem with the theme. I can't properly see which of my navbar items that is currently active. Therefore I want to add a background color to the .active element.

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- MOBILE FIRST -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- THEMES -->
  <!-- <link href="css/theme_black.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <!-- <link href="css/theme_white.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

  <!-- HOMEMADE - these files are local --> 
  <!-- <script src="js/functions.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <link href="css/custom_style.css" rel="stylesheet"> --> 
</head>
<body>
<header id="header" class="header clearfix no-padding">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse no-padding">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" id="navigator">
          <li id="home"><a class="border" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li id="about"><a class="border" href="#">About</a></li>
          <li id="cv"><a class="border" href="#">CV</a></li>
          <li id="contact"><a class="border" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
</body>
```

I am using the following code in my javascript to change the .active item

## functions.js

```
$('#nav li a').click(function() {
  $('#nav li').removeClass();
  $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');
});
```

I do however want to change the background of the active item, and I have tried a couple of different solutions in my css, but none of them work as intended.

## custom_style.css

```
.no-margin {
  margin: 0;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

//some sort of .active {
//  background-color: blue;
//}
```

## EDIT:

Now with a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/819qbftg/2/

Comment: Can you please add a starting point in code (for example a CodePen or JSFiddle).

Comment: I'm currently trying this. However I have trouble getting my bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css files included.. (It seems to not accept them as they are "http" links and not "https". Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Nvm. I found a solution. Fiddle coming up in two secs..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you have to do two things, make sure you address the right item with JavaScript and override the default styling that's been set by the Bootstrap CSS.

*JavaScript (jQuery)*

```
var selector = '.nav li';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

You were addressing the `#nav`, but in your HTML, there was only a **class** with nav, no ID. Also, don't add the class to the `href` attribute.

This JS code will first remove `.active` from all selectors (`.nav li`) before setting it again on the item that's clicked.

*Styling added*

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active> a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active> a:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active> a:hover {
  background: red; /* Anything you want */
}
```

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ys46qo/2/) for a demo.

Comment: Superb answer. You also corrected my error with the identifier ("#") in the javascript. Cheers!

Comment: @Roy where should we add this styling... in bootstrap.css or bootstrap-themes...?

Answer (score 2):

Override these styles...

```
<style>
   .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { color: #DD0000; }
   .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus { color: #DD0000; }
</style>
```

I took your file above and put this style tag at the bottom of the `<head>`.  Seems to do what you're asking.  I usually do this in a separate CSS for the site that is included last in your CSS links.